# Possible to add executable section/segment to ELF binary?

Tags: elf

It's easy to add an empty section with objcopy --add-section.
However, I'd like the added section can be loaded as normal .text section and executable. Which means need modify segment header. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Possible to add executable section/segment to ELF binary?

It's possible in theory, but not in practice: `ELF` files have complicated internal structures, which would all need to be rebuilt.

> Which means need modify segment header

Modifying `Phdr` table is quite easy: it's just a fixed table. But you'll have to move other segments, and update all internal offsets that point into them, which is the hard part.

Comment: I'm think another option, not sure if can meet my expect: Add a new executable section to the end of file, and extend existing loading segment (cover the .text section) to end of the new file. However after patching, the binary can't be loaded... Not sure if other possible solution? Moving sections and segment after .text may possible work, but I need to write a tool to adjust all offset in later section/segment.